# css 100% fluid height misbehaving

Tags: css, image, html, height

2 things (and I'm sure they're related)

1. I would like my lightbox-style `absolute` div (`.g`) to be the height of the page not the window (click on the link in the html to display it)
2. I would like my `img` in the absolute div (`.g img`) to respond to the window height.

Is this possible?  I've tried a number of things having searched extensively but my rudimentary knowledge of html and css is failing me. e.g. if I use `min-height:100%` on `html` then my `div.g` is the height of the page but the main content div (`#d`) doesn't stick to the bottom of the window.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="d">
  <div id="c">
    <p style="margin-bottom:450px"><a href="#a1">click for images</a></p>
    <p>end text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="f">footer</div>
</div>

<div class="g" id="a1">
  <a href="#" class="x"></a>
  <div>
    <a href="#a2"><img src="http://www.JBM-Computing.net/test/img1.png"></a>
    <p><a href="#">click img, or here to close</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="g" id="a2">
  <a href="#" class="x"></a>
  <div>
    <a href="#a1"><img src="http://www.JBM-Computing.net/test/img2.png"></a>
    <p><a href="#">click here to close, or click img</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*      {margin:0;
        padding:0
}
html   {height:100%
}
body   {height:100%;
        font-family:Arial;
        background:lightSteelBlue
}
#d     {position:relative;
        top:2%;
        right:0;
        bottom:2%;
        left:0;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:80%;
        max-width:840px;
        min-height:96%;
        background:white;
        border:solid 1px green
}
#c     {position:relative;
        margin:4% auto 40px;
        max-width:80%;
        padding:5px;
        border:solid 1px red
}
#f     {position:absolute;
        right:10%;
        bottom:0;
        left:10%;
        max-width:80%;
        padding:5px;
        background:lightGrey
}
.g     {position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:100%;
        bottom:100%;
        left:0;
        z-index:4;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:RGBA(0,0,0,.7)
}
.g:target {bottom:0;
           right:0;
           overflow:visible
}
.g a.x {position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:5
}
.g div {position:relative;
        z-index:6;
        margin:8% 8% 0;
        background:powderBlue;
        border:10px solid darkKhaki
}
.g img {display:block;
        max-width:100%;
        margin:auto;
        border:solid 1px blue
}
.g p   {padding:5px
}
```

I've also posted it on [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ToxikJonny/vE4j3/). Resize the window and watch the page react.

It behaves acceptably at the moment but it's not perfect.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** why does `.g:target {bottom:0}` not make the div fill the whole height of the `body`?? It should shouldn't it?

Comment: **FYI**: Ids and classes should be named properly instead of a, b, c.

Comment: Rather than make the background the page height, consider using position:fixed. The image can be responsive within this area. See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/sH8eR/1/

Comment: @Win - I've shortened them for this thread. Out of interest, is there a reason they should be named properly (as it still works)?

Comment: @kthornbloom - thanks but I'd rather not use :fixed as I'd like the ability to zoom in to the images (e.g. on mobiles) and using :fixed makes this impossible as it shifts the image depending on where it's anchored. Is it possible using :absolute?

Comment: @ToxikJonny you can name whatever you want. However, 6 months from now you won't be able to remember what **g** is and where it is used.  ***It is a very bad practice in programming including CSS unless you are obfuscating the code***.

Comment: You can use absolute, but if you scroll, the 'overlay' will scroll with the back and be lost. That's why fixed is usually used in this situation. If you're making a responsive site, won't pinch zooming be disabled anyway?

Comment: @kthornbloom - you're right but I'd like to see if this is possible as some of the images are things like floor plans and I would like people to be able to zoom in and scroll around.

Comment: well, I'd suggest using my solution, but change the modal div to absolute. then you will need JS to determine the height of the page. You can then set this height on the absolute div.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is `.g div - margin:8% 8% 0;` which prevents the pop-up from displaying in full page size.

```
.g div {position:relative;
        z-index:6;
        height: 100%;            <=== Full page size
        box-sizing: border-box;  <=== Prevent vertical scroll bar
        /* margin:8% 8% 0; */    <=== Problem, so comment out
        background:powderBlue;
        border:10px solid darkKhaki
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/W8kxm/](http://jsfiddle.net/W8kxm/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but without the margin it loses the lightbox look and feel. This update causes the img to spill out of the div when you scroll down (click on the image to toggle between a portrait and a landscape image). But the main issue is that the transparent, dark grey background (which is also clickable to close the lightbox) is still not visible when you scroll down below the `.g div` i.e it doesn't overlap the whole page - which is what I'm after.